# How to captalize letter on django rest serialize

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my database i have a nome field, and in this charfield all data is uppercase. I need return in the title format, just title() method does.
example:

data in my field name: **CAFE SANTA CLARA SOLUVEL GRAN. RF 50G-12501**

i need return like that: **Cafe Santa Clara Soluve Gran Rf 50G-12501**

I use django rest serializer to return this data.

Whats the best way to do this? In my model, serializer class or my view?

Tks!

model:

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome.encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome.encode('utf-8')

    categoria = models.ForeignKey(ProdutoCategoria, null=True, blank=True)
    marca = models.ForeignKey(ProdutoMarca, null=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True) #its this column
    unidade = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, db_column='unid')
    ean = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    ncm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65, null=True, decimal_places=2)
    fator = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, null=True, decimal_places=2)
    fornecedor = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    imagem = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_externo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    top = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
```

serializer:

```
class ProdutoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    marca = serializers.CharField(source='marca.nome')
    categoria_pai = serializers.IntegerField(source='categoria.pai.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Produto
        fields = (
            'ean',
            'id',
            'nome',
            'imagem',
            'marca',
            'categoria',
            'categoria_pai'
        )
```

Comment: Why to return it in this format? I will suggest to let the transformation of field to be done at the client side. If you do not want that, in that case you may create serializer methods and map those methods with the fields in case it is something which is to be replicated in many views. If it is for single view. Better transform the serialized result in the view

Answer (score 1):

The best way is use your serializer:

Something like this:

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = ServiceCategorySerializer()

    service = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_service(self, obj):
        return obj.service.upper() if obj.service else None
```

This is the first way :)
The second is to change tour to_representation, like this:

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = ServiceCategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('service', 'category')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(ServiceSerializer, self).to_representation(instance=instance)
        data['service'] = data['service'].lower() if data['service'] else data['services']
        return data
```

The problem is that :) before each save - you should reverse the process - especially in the second case. But in the first scenario - you will also get from the front the changed value, so basically after some finite time you will have all DB rows rewritten ;)

As someone suggested - why you do not want to do this on Front side?

Answer (score 0):

```
## First Letter Capital.
def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name.capitalize()
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code.